# Database Design - table creation & connecting records

Tags: mysql, database-design

Ive been trying to understand the thoughts of the person who designed this database. I want to know what this procedure is called and why its beneficial. The person who designed this is gone and I want to learn why.

Say I have two tables, **Users** and **Roles**

**Users**

```
create table my_users (
    userid int,
    primary key (userid),
    username varchar(255)
);
insert into my_users (userid, username) values (1, 'Stack User 1');
```

**Roles**

```
create table my_roles (
    roleid int,
    primary key (roleid),
    rolename varchar(255)
);
insert into my_roles (roleid, rolename) values (1, 'Admin'), (2, 'Local User'), (3, 'DB Owner');
```

These tables are mapped together called **UserRoles**

```
create table UserRoles (
    userroleid int,
    primary key (userroleid),
    userid int,
    roleid int
);
```

Is the reason for this so that there can be many roles to one user?

something like this:

```
insert into UserRoles (userid, roleid) values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3);
```

What would be the reason for a column in my_users for just one roleid?

```
create table my_users_2 (
    userid int,
    primary key (userid),
    username varchar(255),
    roleid int
);
insert into my_users_2 (userid, username, roleid) values (1, 'Stack Exchange', 1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the reason for this so that there can be many roles to one user?

Yes, this is normal. Common many-to-many (M:N) relation. But your structure does not set any relation because there is no any FOREIGN KEY in the table. And in most cases the values pair `(userid, roleid)` in such table must be unique.

There is another thing which makes no sence - and this thing is synthetic primary key. In current structure it is excess. The next structure with composite primary key is more reasonable:

```sql
create table UserRoles (
    userid int,
    roleid int,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, roleid),
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES my_users (userid),
    FOREIGN KEY (roleid) REFERENCES my_roles (roleid)
);
```

When the relation is an entity itself (and it have some additional properties and/or it is used in another M:N relation), then the synthetic key is reasonable. In this case you'd provide `(userid, roleid)` uniqueness by creating according unique index:

```sql
create table UserRoles (
    userroleid int,
    primary key (userroleid),
    userid int,
    roleid int,
    UNIQUE (userid, roleid),
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES my_users (userid),
    FOREIGN KEY (roleid) REFERENCES my_roles (roleid)
);
```

---

> What would be the reason for a column in my_users for just one roleid?

If the user can have only one role then the role is an attribute of the user, the relation will be 1:N, and according relational column will be a part of `my_users` table with according FOREIGN KEY relation to `my_roles`. The table `UserRoles` not needed.

Comment: Good answer. It reads a little bit off, beginning from *"There is another thing"*. Might read better as "There is one thing which makes no sense - and that is the synthetic primary key. In the current schema it is unnecessary. The following schema with a composite primary key is more reasonable:"

Comment: I think there are some programming standards or guidelines that recommend having a primary ID column in every table, even if it's not normally referenced.

Comment: @Barmar On a purely many:many join table it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Charlieface I agree, but some seem to be sticklers for this. I think it has something to do with efficiency of clustered indexes.

Comment: @Barmar I agree when we tell about *entity* table - its PK column is entity instance identifier. But in M:N-relation table - 50/50.. only when the relation is an entity itself.

Comment: @Akina I'm not saying I agree with these guidelines, but some organizations are pedantic about it.

Answer (score 4):

(Augmenting Akina's Answer)

For 1:many (1 role has many users; each user can have at most 1 role), add `roleid` to `myusers`.

For many:many (potentially many roles for each user, *and* many user per role), this is more efficient than Akina's suggestion:

```
create table UserRoles (
    userid int,
    roleid int,
    PRIMARY KEY (userid, roleid),  -- for lookup one way, and as the PK
    INDEX       (roleid, userid),  -- for lookup the other way
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES my_users (userid),
    FOREIGN KEY (roleid) REFERENCES my_roles (roleid)
);
```

There is no need for the extra column `userroleid`.